# NGINX simple proxy doesnt work, get 404 on location

Tags: nginx

I am trying to learn nginx and this simple test gives me 404 when going to localhost:81/test. I basically want the same index page to show up on /test.

I'm using nginx from windows on my local computer. Downloaded from http://nginx.org/en/docs/windows.html and starts by running ./nginx.exe in bash-terminal

tldr: localhost:81 gives me the indexpage and localhost:81/test gives me 404

my nginx.conf:

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;


    server {
        listen 81 ;
        server_name localhost;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }
        location /test {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nginx is looking for files at `./html/test/index.html` - try using: `alias html;`

Comment: i tried  server_name localhost alias html; and still get 404

Comment: The `alias` needs to be inside the `location /test` block. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias).

Comment: Ahh yes i have to remove root from location /test and only use alias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to replace `root html` with `alias html` in the `location /test`-block